# Why “dressed in blue” instead of “dressing in blue”?

Tags: participles, reduced-relative-clauses

> 1. The girl **dressed** in blue is my girlfriend.
> 2. The girl **dressing** in blue is my girlfriend.

I know the first sentence is correct, but how about the second one? Why do we say "The girl who dresses in blue is my girlfriend." but no one seems to say "The girl dressing in blue..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dressing" is often used in context in a way that can be interchanged with "wearing," but taken for its literal meaning, it's the act of getting dressed. We can talk about what someone *habitually* dresses in by using the present simple, but when we use the present participle "dressing," that's a specific action currently taking place—she's currently changing her clothes. Definitely not the same.

Comment: She's dressed in blue = she's wearing blue today. She dresses in blue = she habitually wears blue. She's dressing in blue = she's putting her clothes on now.